# Using Grafana to analyse/massage data from OpenTSDB

Tags: plugins, grafana, opentsdb

I am using grafana to plot graphs from OpenTSDB for my performance tests. Now i want to perform certain analysis/data massaging to calculate the results of the test. Is there a way to do so?
Can grafana plugins help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently only one option:

Use [Bosun](http://bosun.org/) and it's [Grafana plugin](https://github.com/bosun-monitor/bosun-grafana-app) between OpenTSDB and Grafana. 
This way you can use the [Bosun's expression language](http://bosun.org/expressions) to process data before displaying it.

In the future it might be possible to use Grafana itself to manipulate data using [Meta Queries](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/3677)

Comment: Thanks i ll give it a try